# Can two 3D lines define a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have two **non-intersecting non-parallel** lines in three dimensional space can they define a plane? It's logical to say that if two lines intersect or are parallel that they *are* on the same plane, but I just can't visualize it the other way around.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No, by definition. The generate the whole space. To visualise think of two non-intersecting edges of a tetrahedron  $ABCD$, say the lines $(AB)$ and $(CD)$.

Comment: There is a unique plane that neither of the lines intersects and that both lines have the same distance to.

Comment: I would +1 that if it was an answer, @random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary for those $2$ lines to define a plane: consider for example the $x$-axis and the line defined by shifting the $y$ axis by $1$ in the $z$-direction

Comment: Ah I see. Now does that mean that the linear combination of those two lines is not a plane? I mean if they can't define any plane how can their linear combination fill a plane?

Comment: What do you call a linear combination of lines?

Comment: Do you mean the linear combination of the vectors defining the lines?

Comment: You seem to not see a line is not necessarily a sub-vector space (except if it passes through the origin) – it s ‘only’ an affine subspace.

Comment: Yes, I mean the linear combination of vectord defining that line.

Comment: @Janekmuric Consider the following. Let $\vec{v}=(x,y,z)$ be an arbitrary vector in $\Bbb{R}^3$ such that $z\neq0$. From $$\vec{v}=x(1,0,0)+z(0,y/z,1)$$ we see that $\vec{v}$ is a linear combination of two vectors, one from each line on asdf's answer. If $z=0$ then you can write $$\vec{v}=x(1,0,0)+(0,2y,1)-(0,y,1)$$ as a slightly more complicated linear combination. The point is that if the line not through the origin is not parallel to the other, its points are vectors pointing at distinct directions, and we can take advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Two lines $r$ and $s$ in ${\Bbb R}^3$ that do not meet in a point and are not parallel are never contained in a plane.

But you can play the following game: write parametric equations $r(t)$ and $s(t)$ for $r$ and $s$ respectively and for any value of $t\in\Bbb R$ let $\ell_t$ the line joining the point $r(t)$ and the point $s(t)$ (well defined, since $r$ and $s$). As $t$ varies, the line $\ell_t$ describe a surface $S$ which may have some interesting properties (when $r$ and $s$ are parallel not coincident, $S$ is the plane where the two lines sit in).